# Cannot impersonate and install apps silently. How to install apps silently or without user interaction from WinForms C# application?

Tags: c#, winforms, installation

I am working on package installer tool which requires installing app from that tool without user interaction and installation should get started after impersonating with Administrator's account.
Here is the code I am using currently. But forget about silent installation it's not even impersonating administrator. Can anybody help me achieving silent installation through impersonating in this WinForms C# application?

```
private void SilentInstaller(string dir, string package, string option, long PckgID)
    {
        if (File.Exists(dir + @"\" + package))
        {
            Pckg_Ws_ExecModel obj = PendingPackages.Where(x => x.Pckg_ID == PckgID).FirstOrDefault();
            if (obj.Status != "Installing" || obj.Status != "Installed")
            {
                obj.Status = "Installing";
                packageWS_service.UpdatePackageWorkstation(obj);
                SafeTokenHandle safeTokenHandle;
                string domainName = "corp";
                string userName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["xusername"];
                string password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["xpassword"];
                const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;
                const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Started myProcess");
                    // Call LogonUser to obtain a handle to an access token.
                    bool returnValue = LogonUser(userName, domainName, password,
                        LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,
                        out safeTokenHandle);
                    if (returnValue)
                    {
                        using (safeTokenHandle)
                        {
                            //if (processingPackage.Pckg_ID > 0)
                            //    AddEvent(processingPackage.Pckg_ID, "Download Started");
                            Console.WriteLine("Before impersonation: " + WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
                            using (WindowsIdentity newId = new WindowsIdentity(safeTokenHandle.DangerousGetHandle()))
                            {
                                using (WindowsImpersonationContext impersonatedUser = newId.Impersonate())
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("After impersonation: " + WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name + "\n");
                                    Process myProcess = new Process();
                                    myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                                    myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                                    myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                                    myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = dir + @"\" + package;
                                    myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/user:Administrator \"cmd /K " + "" + "\"";
                                    myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                                    myProcess.Start();
                                    myProcess.PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.BelowNormal;
                                    myProcess.WaitForExit();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("Prog should have waited for exit to print this");
                    //MSGError("Installation completed");
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    //MSGError("Installation failed");
                    //MSGError(e.ToString());
                    errorService.AddError(new ErrorModel() { Ws_ID = MachineName(), Usr = UserName(), Pckg_ID = PckgID, Error1 = e.Message });
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Errors.Detect = true;
            //MSGError("Installer no longer exist");
            errorService.AddError(new ErrorModel() { Ws_ID = MachineName(), Usr = UserName(), Pckg_ID = PckgID, Error1 = "Installer no longer exist" });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't do this.  Use MSIExec with the silent install flags.

Comment: Hi! If you can’t impersonate the Admin user, can you please rewrite your question since it’s not what the title is asking for. Besides that, can you try removing the `/user:Administrator` because you are running inside an impersonation context

Comment: @rory.ap can you please provide any example for it

Comment: @emmanuel After removing  /user:Administrator  also getting the same issue.

Comment: @MurtuzaKhan -- as with any command-line exe, use "msiexec /?" to get info on how to use it.  Or just google it.  There's plenty of info out there.